# Reputation loss from edited question removal

Tags: discussion

Recently many questions have been removed which i had edited to increase readability or representation.[image]
Is there some rule or specification which state which kind of question should be edited so that they are not removed in future?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's great to help questions with quality problems through edits. It's explicitly encouraged by the site, and the greatest service you can do to users that don't quite know how to ask a good question yet.

The activity comes with an inherent risk, though: the questions may get closed, downvoted, and subsequently deleted, letting your editing efforts go to waste. Stack Overflow  gets over 12,000 new questions every day. Harsh quality control is a necessity to keep the place going, and you can't help every question and user "make it" here.

You'll probably have  to live with this happening from time to time. I looked up a couple of the deleted questions; it wasn't always obvious they were going to be closed even to me, with seven years' experience on the site.

In general, try to avoid questions that

- don't make any sense even after editing (like "[bitmap image defragmentation program useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816477/bitmap-image-defragmentation-program-useless)", which just read

  > I wrote a program that defragment a bitmap image(like hard disk defragmentation ), but I didn't find a use for it. Any suggestions ?
- ask for definitions of terms that are easy to look up ("Difference between keylogger and keyboard recorder")
- are very likely to be a duplicate of an existing question (Google the question's title before editing, and see what results come up.)

Part of it is just down to experience that you will get over time, recognizing which questions have a chance of working here, and which don't.

**If an edit wouldn't make a question fully on-topic and useful by our standards, it's not worth investing your time.**